# Birthday Finder Project - Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

For my school project, I have to make a python script that tells the user how many years until they reach the age of 100, and how many days until their next birthday. I have figured the first problem, but I have no idea how to address the second part of this project. In summary: How do I get the days until the users next birthday on Python (3.2).
This is what I have so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

name = input("What's your name?")
print("Nice to meet you %s." % (name))
print("What day is your birthday? (MMDDYYYY)")
birthdate = input()
birthday = int(birthdate[2:3])
birthyear = int(birthdate[4:])
print (birthyear)
now = datetime.now()
current_year = now.year
current_month = now.month
current_day = now.day
currentAge = current_year - birthyear
age = current_year - birthyear
print (now)
print (age)
year_till_100 = str(100 - currentAge)
print ("You will be 100 in %s years." % (year_till_100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic example with an arbitrary date:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> diff = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 1) - dt.datetime.now()
>>> diff.days
52
>>>
```

In your case, diff would be something along these lines:

```
diff = dt.datetime(birthyear+1, int(birthdate[0:2]), birthday) - now
                                            # ^^^ your birthmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, not the best solution.

```
from datetime import date


born = '06151995'
yearInt = int(born[-4:])
dayInt = int(born[2:4])
monthInt = int(born[0:2])

d0 = date(yearInt, monthInt, dayInt)
d1 = date(yearInt + 100, monthInt, dayInt)
delta = d1 - d0

print delta.days
```

EDIT:
This is how many days since they were born tho.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions,

```
birthday = int(birthdate[2:3])
```

is only slicing one digit from the `birthdate` string input, should probably include 2 digit days:

```
birthday = int(birthdate[2:4]
```

Similarly, you'll need a birthmonth to determine number of days until next birthday:

```
birthmonth = int(birthdate[0:2])
```

Now you've got all the components necessary to calculate the days until the next birthday:

```
days_til_next_bd = datetime(current_year+1, birthmonth, birthday) - datetime.now()
print ("%s days until your next birthday." % days_til_next_bd.days)
```

Demo:

> What day is your birthday? (MMDDYYYY)
>   09112001
>   You will be 100 in 85 years.
>   305 days until your next birthday.